# how to insert html type=time into a database

Tags: php

hello guys i need help on inserting my html type-time into my database..this is my form html.

```
<tr>
  <td><font color="black">Time:</td>
  <td colspan = "2"><input type = "time" name = "time_hr"></td>
  </tr>
```

this is the post method

```
@$time_hr=$_POST['time_hr'];
```

this is my query

```
$query = " INSERT INTO receipt VALUES ('','$cust_data','$cust_address','$cust_id',
          '$sets','$time_hr',$cold','$hot','$price','$q','$sum','$deposit','$amount','$booking_date' ,'PENDING')";
```

i was wondering how to insert it into my database.
my xampp structure for time is varchar.

please and thank you and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: the error is it can not be save into the database

Comment: print this query and try this directly in phpmyadmin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in your query. You are missing one single quote near `$cold` variable. Try following query.

```
$query = " INSERT INTO receipt VALUES ('', '$cust_data', '$cust_address', '$cust_id', 
'$sets', '$time_hr', '$cold', '$hot', '$price', '$q', '$sum', '$deposit', '$amount', 
'$booking_date', 'PENDING')";
```

Also try `echo mysql_error()` to know if any other error is there in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert Query is wrong. Please follow the below example

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

And take varchar datatype into your database value 60

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
@$time_hr=$_POST['time_hr'];
```

Change to this

```
$time_hr=$_POST['time_hr'];
```

then your query works

```
INSERT INTO receipt 
VALUES('','$cust_data','$cust_address','$cust_id','$sets','$time_hr',
$cold','$hot','$price','$q','$sum','$deposit','$amount','$booking_date' ,'PENDING')";
```

Comment: does not make sense - you know what the @ does?